# The import edu cannot be resolved on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm totally a freshman in Java and programming, and I'm studying algorithms on coursera. I want to practice by writing a simple BinarySearch and following the instructions on a book, but when I try to use the `algs4.jar` library provided by the book online sources, the library cannot be resolved:

[image]

It goes wrong when I try to import `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn` and Eclipse tells me the import `edu` cannot be resolved. I have already put the jar file as referenced libraries by following the instructions (add `algs4.jar` to the classpath variable to the build path of a project via *Project > Properties: Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs*)

Comment: Just to make sure there isn't a typo, post the full line for that import statement _in text_ for us.

Answer (score 3):

You have a **`module-info.java`** which means you are using the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which is optional but which when using it **requires specifying used modules** to be able to import things from them.

Do one of the following:

- **Delete `src/module-info.java`** to not use JPMS
- Go to the line with the error, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and choose the quick fix that adds the missing `requires` statement: *Add 'requires ...' to module-info.java*